# Passing elipses as an argument to java method

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have a Java method which accepts arguments in ellipses format. This method in turns call an api which again accepts parameters in ellipses format:

```
public void myMethod(String a, String... listOfParam){

   //Method Signature of anotherAPI is anotherAPI(String input, Object ... listOfParams)

   //I call anotherAPI method as described below.
   String result = anotherAPI(a, listOfParam); 
}
```

However, when I pass `listOfParams` as arguments, I get `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Please let me know the correct approach in this case.

## Edit

I am calling AmazonDynamoDB Java API's 
(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?index-all.html) `addHashOnlyPrimaryKeys` method :

The client method is as below :

```
public static List<Item> getAllItems(String tableName,String primaryKeyName, String ... listOfKeys){
    List<Item> itemList = null;
    System.out.println(listOfKeys.toString());
    TableKeysAndAttributes tkaa = new TableKeysAndAttributes(tableName);
    tkaa.addHashOnlyPrimaryKey(primaryKeyName, listOfKeys);
    BatchGetItemOutcome outcome = dynamoDB.batchGetItem(tkaa);
    itemList = outcome.getTableItems().get(tableName);
    return itemList;
}
```

I testing this method as :

```
List<Item> listOfItems = AmazonDynamoDBUtil.getAllItems("myTable","data","1","2","3","4");
```

Here is data is of type String.

However, the exception which I am getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: value type: class [Ljava.lang.String;
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.InternalUtils.toAttributeValue(InternalUtils.java:221)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.InternalUtils.toAttributeValueMap(InternalUtils.java:535)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.InternalUtils.toAttributeValueMap(InternalUtils.java:547)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.BatchGetItemImpl.doBatchGetItem(BatchGetItemImpl.java:84)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.BatchGetItemImpl.batchGetItem(BatchGetItemImpl.java:58)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB.batchGetItem(DynamoDB.java:154)
        at awsdynamodb.AmazonDynamoDBUtil.getAllItems(AmazonDynamoDBUtil.java:63)
```

Please let me know what can be wrong with this approach.

Comment: can you post the implementation of the anotherAPI() method? and what type is listOfParam parameter?

Comment: btw, `elipses` are called `varargs`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please improve your question with the type of your parameter and the implementation of anotherAPI. In other words, make your question more complete. Provide enough details so we can indeed help you.

Comment: You can pass an array to a varargs parameter. A `List` is not an array.

Comment: Tell us more about this mysterious api.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete info. I have updated the question, Hope I am able to explain now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code runs fine for me, albeit with a warning (which you can get rid of by casting the second parameter of the call to anotherAPI() to Object[]):

```
public class Test
{
  public static String anotherAPI(final String a, final Object... listOfParam)
  {
    for (final Object param : listOfParam)
      System.out.println(param);

    return "Test";
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args)
  {
    myMethod("a", "This", "is", "a", "test");
  }

  public static void myMethod(final String a, final String... listOfParam)
  {
    final String result = anotherAPI(a, listOfParam);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

with the output:

```
This
is
a
test
Test
```

I think the implementation of anotherAPI() doesn't allow for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMethod("test 1");
        myMethod("test 2", "a");
        myMethod("test 3", "a", "b", "c");
    }

    public static void myMethod(String a, String... listOfParam) {
        anotherAPI(a, listOfParam);
    }

    private static void anotherAPI(String a, String... listOfParam) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String p : listOfParam) {
            sb.append(p);
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        System.out.println(a + ": " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

produces the expected result:

```
test 1: 
test 2: a, 
test 3: a, b, c,
```

From a Java point of view `listOfParam` as `String...` is a `String[]` array.

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't support that method call (hence the `unsupported` exception). Nothing to do with ellipsis. Don't call that method, it won't work.

Comment: but if I pass listOfParam[0] as an argument, It works

Comment: Then you're probably calling a single argument version of the method. I.e. a totally different method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys , it seems I was calling `addHashOnlyPrimaryKey` instead of `addHashOnlyPrimaryKeys` :)